# desc table in mysql say Null is No but default is NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql, null, default, default-value

I am using `mysql` for a project. When I did 'desc table_name', I see that the tabular output shows the `Null` of the field is set to `No`, but then 'Default' is set to `NULL`. How can a field not have a `Null` but then default is `Null` itself?

```
mysql> desc users;                                                                                 
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+----------------------------+----------------+  
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default                    | Extra          |  
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+----------------------------+----------------+  
| id              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                       | auto_increment |  
| created_at      | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL                       |                |  
| updated_at      | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL                       |                |  
| email           | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                       |                |  
| password        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                       |                |  
| remember_token  | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL                       |                |  
| profile_pic     | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | img/profile/profilepic.jpg |                |  
| activation_code | varchar(255)     | YES  | UNI | NULL                       |                |  
| status_id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 1                          |                |  
| profile_id      | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL                       |                |  
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+----------------------------+----------------+  
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: default is null because it is the value state before the value is inserted by you .

Comment: the No value in null column mean that for the related  field the null value are not allowed . ... this value  is assigned  during the table/fileds  creation ..

Comment: if `DEFAULT is NULL` and you dont provide the field, the `INSERT` will fail because the field doesnt accept `NULL`

Comment: Can we interpret it like this. Default column says what goes in the cell, and Null (No) column is the constraint on what goes in the cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfectly legal combination. It means that when you try to insert a new row and do not explicitly specify this column's value, it would default to `null` and thus error out. This combination is often used as a way to force you to explicitly assign a value to the column instead of just relying on defaults.

Comment: Since the column is a primary key it makes perfect sense that a value is always inserted.

Answer (score 1):

1. we should know this:

- `Null(NO)`: means this column couldn't accept a "NULL" value
- `Null(YES)`: means this column could accept a "NULL" value
- `Default`: means this column's default value :)

2. we should know: in MySQL, blank is not equal to `NULL`, if we insert nothing into a column, it will stay nothing(it will not insert a "NULL" into this column)
3. so, when `Null(NO)` comes with `Default(NULL)`, if we insert nothing to this value, it'll have a default value "NULL" and it 'll conflict with the constraint, then it'll throw a exception